# figure TIKZ with a trajecotry visiting regions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, function

I want to create the following figure with tikz with a green backgroud.

[image: figure]

This is what I ve done so far (with circles)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,-1) rectangle (4,4); % E
\draw (0,0) ++(45:2) circle (0.5); % B
\fill[color=green!30] \E;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \A;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \B;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \C;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\E}{(-4,-1) rectangle (4,4)}
\newcommand{\A}{(0,0) ++(135:3) circle (0.7)}
\newcommand{\B}{(0,0) ++(45:1) circle (0.7)}
\newcommand{\C}{(0,0) ++(50:3.5) circle (1)}
```

Do you have some ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: side note: put your code between \``` code \```

Comment: Do you want the red circles to look like beans?. How curvy do you want the path to be?

Comment: @anis to be exact I wanted a 'random' shape that is just connected but also have a smooth boundary. Since circles are just a very particular case.

Comment: Please check the pgfmanual e.g. for control points, Bezier, and pathes made from more than 2 points. Also check for arrows. Also check for the decoration tikzlib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
dot/.pic={\fill (0,0) circle[radius=4pt];},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\draw[blue!50!black, fill=green!30, ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (8,5);
\draw[blue!50!black, fill=red!50, thick, closed, shift={(2,3.5)}, scale=0.6] (1.5,0) foreach \n in {1,...,5} {.. ([shift=(\n*360/6:1.5)]rnd,rnd)};
\draw[blue!50!black, fill=red!50, thick, closed, shift={(6,3)},   scale=0.6] (1.5,0) foreach \n in {1,...,5} {.. ([shift=(\n*360/6:1.5)]rnd,rnd)};
\draw[blue!50!black, fill=red!50, thick, closed, shift={(4,1.5)}, scale=0.6] (1.5,0) foreach \n in {1,...,5} {.. ([shift=(\n*360/6:1.5)]rnd,rnd)};
\draw[blue!50!black, tension=0.5, ->-=0.55, ultra thick] (1,1)pic{dot} .. (2,3.5) .. (4,3) .. (6,3) .. (4,1.5) .. (3,1) .. (5,0.5) .. (7,1)pic{dot};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Green rectangle with three red shapes and a path]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: +1, again we had the same idea, but you beat me this time!!! ;-D